# UIViewController's view has weird 20px

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Hello Guys I am facing a wierd behaviour in my app the case is like this :

From view controller(A) present another view controller (B) which has a `UIWebView` that will open an URL, but sometime the URL is Video link,
Sot he video starts playing in full screen and when finish and tap on Done (Dismiss Video player) and then dismiss the Controller (B) a weird 20px appeared at the bottom of view controller(A) and the whole app will lose the 20px in all screens.[image]

Any one has idea for what is happening, I am certain sure that it caused by playing video through `UIWebView`

**Update 1** :
I just figured out that this could be related to the iOS itself when playing videos whether from video file or from video url (since both will be played using the same player).
My experiment was on Facebook app when I post the same links used in my app inside Facebook app then try to play the videos from the links and the behaviour showed !

I wish if could someone help to confirm if playing videos causing problems on the UI.

Comment: Have you added status bar in your view controller A ? have you added status bar in your view controller B?

Comment: @NiravPatel what do you mean with add?
but for me the status bar is added all the time in the App

Comment: As a hack could you not just increase the white area to cover the gap ?

Comment: @GuybrushThreepwood I am not controlling that gap its just happen! unless I don't know what do you mean

Comment: I mean it's probably not worth the time and effort to fix - just cover it up by making you background longer ?

Comment: The problem like I said before is that the whole App will be shifted 20 up, I wish if it only happens in that controller only that will be more easy